# Does zend have an image view helper

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-view

I could type the html for an image in my view

```
<img src="">
```

but was wondering if zend has an image view helper like it has with urls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it does not. It has TinySrc view helper though, so you could use it if you really want. There are also custom made image helpers, e.g. [Image view helper for Zend Framework](http://jamandcheese-on-phptoast.com/2009/10/15/image-view-helper-for-zend-framework/)

Answer (score 2):

No it doesn't. And it probably will never have, because it's trivial to write helpers like this one.

However, for such cases there is [`Zend_View_Helper_HtmlElement`](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/core/Zend_View/Helper/Zend_View_Helper_HtmlElement.html), which should be subclassed to implement needed functionality for HTML tags.

You should write your own, or use one of the [img helpers shared by php community](http://www.google.com/search?&q=zend+view+helper+img).

Answer (score 1):

No. Zend Framework doesn't contain this helper. But always you can write this helpers yourself. It is easy. Example of customize image helper: http://blog.amnuts.com/2007/10/03/simple-image-view-helper-for-zend-framework/

Comment: My link only shows, that you can write your own flexible helper.